Suspense does not work with Nextjs learning example
I started to learn NextJS and I finihsed the tutorial.
I pulled the final result of the example from final-example repo on github. I want to test Suspense effect on on a component without loading.tsx which shows a loading status for the whole page, so I deleted loading.tsx under app > dashboard > (overview), and also add 5 seconds delay to fetchRevenue call in app > lib > data.js:

fetchEvenue is called in app > ui > dashboard > revenue-chart.tsx

and the RevenueChart component is used in app > dashboard > (overview)

However, when I click "Home" on side menu, Suspense does not work. The dashboard page just freezed until the server finishes fetching data. I expect the dashboard page is loaded immediately and the revenue card shows loading status when I click "Home" on side menu . This is same when I "refesh" the page.
Here is the recorded video:
https://imgur.com/YamjkId
I searched for answeres online but cannot find any... did I missing anything?

Edit the post to include where you call fetcgRevenue

I Just added the page, component links.

It works as expected doesn't freeze. While you see a loading spinner in the browser tab it doesn't block the page. the rest of the page still streaming as expected. If you see different results, share a repo.
